# C socket intermittently resetting connection and not receiving full request from python requests

Tags: python, c, python-requests

I have a python program that I want to communicate with a C program over http.  I am using requests in python to send some json data to socket in C.

Sometimes, python spits out a "connection reset by peer" error and I can't figure it out.  When I get this error, all but the content of the request is sent and received by the C program.  In my application, I am also making requests from a client written in Go. With that client I am never getting these errors, which is why I think I'm missing some configuration or easy solution in the requests library.  Why is this happening and what might solve my problem?

Here's a simple example; the socket stuff is clearly what I'm not super familiar with:

The C server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define RECV_BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    int option = 1;
    int socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
    if (socketfd < 0)
    {
        perror("failed to start socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("failed to bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(socketfd, 1000) != 0)
    {
        perror("listen error");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[RECV_BUF_SIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        int addrlen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        int clientfd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &addrlen);
        if (clientfd < 0)
        {
            perror("accept error");
        }
        else
        {
            int n_recv = recv(clientfd, buf, RECV_BUF_SIZE, 0);

            // print everything, character by character.
            char* tmp_buf = buf;
            while (n_recv--) printf("%c", *tmp_buf++);
            printf("\n\n****************************\n\n");

            FILE* res = fdopen(clientfd, "w");
            fprintf(res, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
            fclose(res);
            shutdown(clientfd, SHUT_RDWR);
            close(clientfd);
        }
    }
}
```

The Python request script:

```
import requests

json_data = {
    "hello": "thanks"
}

requests.post("http://localhost:8080", json=json_data)
```

Thank-you!

Comment: In C, `recv` is not guaranteed to return everything in one call.  It is intended to be used in a loop.  Sometimes you get lucky and everything you want to read is already in the OS buffers, but if you're a bit quicker, you may only get the headers, and the packet with the payload has not arrived.

Comment: In practice, this means you need to either: read the headers to find out how much you need to receive, or have the client close the socket so you can use the EOF to know when you're done reading.

Comment: Sweet thank-you! In my situation, I do have some characters that symbolise the end of the data so I can just receive until then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the server communication with the client, there are several small problems, like incorrect variable types and lack of error checking.

I've prefixed my comments with `>>` and used 'conditional compile to show how I replaced certain parts of the OPs code with suggested improvements.

caveat: since the server does not know the expected number of bytes to receive from the client, the answer does not include a loop, trying to retrieve all the bytes expected from the client

```
char buf[ RECV_BUF_SIZE +1 ];  // >> +1 for string terminator

while (1)
{
    // >> the third parameter is a 'socklen_t', not an 'int'
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int clientfd = 
        accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &addrlen);
    if (clientfd < 0)
    {
        perror("accept error");
    }

    else
    {
        // >>recv() returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`
        ssize_t n_recv = recv(clientfd, buf, RECV_BUF_SIZE, 0);

        #if 0

            // >>this takes WAY too long, so the connection
            // >>could timeout
            // print everything, character by character.
            char* tmp_buf = buf;
            while (n_recv--) printf("%c", *tmp_buf++);

        #else

            if( n_recv < 0 )
            {  // then an error occurred
                perror( "recv failed" );
                write( clientfd, 
                       "receive error", 
                       sizeof( "receive error" ) );
                close( clientfd );
            }

            else if( n_recv == 0 )
            {  // then client closed connection
                printf( "%s\n", 
                        "client closed connection" );
                close( clientfd );
            }

            else
            { // some data received from client
                buf[ n_recv ] = '\0';  // terminate string
                printf( "%s\n", buf );
            }

        #endif

        printf("\n\n****************************\n\n");

        #if 0

            FILE* res = fdopen(clientfd, "w");
            fprintf(res, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
            fclose(res);
            shutdown(clientfd, SHUT_RDWR);
            close(clientfd);

        #else

            ssize_t writeBytes;
            if( (writeBytes = 
                 write( clientfd, 
                        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n", 
                        strlen( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" ) ) ) 
                        != strlen( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" ) )
            { // then incomplete write
                printf( "%s\n",  
                        "write didn't write all bytes to client" );
            }

            close( clientfd );

        #endif
    }
}
```